# Flutter : Trying pass a variable to next screen based on DropDownButton input

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dropdownbutton

I am trying to reduce a products(smartphone) price based on   user dropdown  input & pass the price to next screen. My code has no error & runs perfectly but the problem is, it reduces price based on only one switch statement (the initial one selected globally for dropdown value) because `setState` method is working only on changing dropdown value displayed on screen, not in the switch statement containing function.  Can someone help me on how to solve this. I tried many things, but nothing helped. Below is my code (It's long, so I  skipped widget building parts & designing parts here).

Value has been defined like this

```dart
   double price = 18000;  
   String bdropDownValue = 'Less than 6 hours'; //initialvalue
    final List<String> bItems = [
    'Less than 6 hours',
    'Less than 12 hours',
    'Less than 24 hours'],
```

**DropdownButtonFormField**

```dart
DropdownButtonFormField(value: bdropDownValue,
                        items: bItems.map((bItems) {
                          return DropdownMenuItem(
                            value: bItems,
                            child: Text(bItems),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                        onChanged: (String? value) {
                          setState(() {
                            bdropDownValue = value!;
                          });
                        },
                        ),
                  /// button used to calculate next
                   TextButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            calculator(bdropDownValue);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "confirm",
                            ),
```

I am using this method to calculate

```dart
void calculator(String bdropDownValue) {
    switch (bdropDownValue) {
      case 'Less than 6 hours':
        price = price - 3000;
        break;
      case 'Less than 12 hours':
        price = price - 1500;
        break;
      case 'Less than 24 hours':
        price = price - 1000;
        break;
    }
```

And using `Navigator` like this inside calculator method

```dart
Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => priceScreen(
                  price: price,
                )));
  }
}
```

Comment: can you tell me the navigator.push method is inside the calculator method. Please  format the code properly.

Comment: Yes its inside the calculator method .. i am using navigator to push the calculated price into next screen

Comment: Please check the example below and let me know if you are still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the example that I have added below it works perfectly fine.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MainHomePage());
  }
}

class MainHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MainHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainHomePageState createState() => _MainHomePageState();
}

class _MainHomePageState extends State<MainHomePage> {
  double price = 18000;
  String bdropDownValue = 'Less than 6 hours'; //initialvalue
  final List<String> bItems = [
    'Less than 6 hours',
    'Less than 12 hours',
    'Less than 24 hours'
  ];

  void calculator(String bdropDownValue) {
    var actualPrice = price;
    switch (bdropDownValue) {
      case 'Less than 6 hours':
        actualPrice = actualPrice - 3000;
        break;
      case 'Less than 12 hours':
        actualPrice = actualPrice - 1500;
        break;
      case 'Less than 24 hours':
        actualPrice = actualPrice - 1000;
        break;
    }

    Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => PriceScreen(
                  price: actualPrice,
                )));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            DropdownButtonFormField(
              value: bdropDownValue,
              items: bItems.map((bItems) {
                return DropdownMenuItem(
                  value: bItems,
                  child: Text(bItems),
                );
              }).toList(),
              onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  bdropDownValue = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                calculator(bdropDownValue);
              },
              child: Text(
                "confirm",
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PriceScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final double price;
  const PriceScreen({Key key, this.price}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: Text(price.toString()),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Glad it worked for you, happy coding.